# my baseball program should run but I just can't find the problem why it won't. look program over

Tags: c++, visual-c++

This program uses arrays to hold baseball scores for 9 innings.  It calculates the high scoring team for each inning and the overall winner of the game.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

const int n = 9;

void PrintInput(char[], int[], char[], int[]);
void InningWinner(char[], int[], char[], int[]);

int main()
{
    int scores1[n];
    int scores2[n];
    char team1[n], team2[n];

         PrintInput(team1,scores1,team2,scores2);
    InningWinner(team1,scores1,team2,scores2);

   return 0;
}

void PrintInput(char t1[], int s1[], char t2[], int s2[])
{
    cout << "\n********************************************************************\n";

    cout << "Team 1: " << t1 << " ";
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        cout << setw(5) << s1[i];
    }
    cout <<  "\n";
    cout << "Team 2: " << t2 << " ";
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        cout << setw(5) << s2[i];
    }
}

 void InningWinner(char t1[], int s1[], char t2[], int s2[])
{
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        if (s1[i] > s2[i])
            cout << endl << t1 << " Wins Inning " << i + 1 << endl;
        else if (s2[i] > s1[i])
            cout << endl << t2 << " Wins Inning " << i + 1 << endl;
        else if (s1[i] == s2[i])
            cout << endl << " Inning " << i+1 << " ends in a TIE" << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Format code by selecting it and pressing CTRL+K. Use the preview!

Comment: Also, you may want to explain what exactly doesn't work.

Comment: Are you missing some code?  I don't see where your char arrays (assuming they are strings, why not char *?) are initialized.  Also, what is the error/behavior you are seeing when you run the program?

Answer (score 2):

All your arrays are used without explicit initialization, which will produced undefined results.

Comment: Though not the reason, but good to point out that the array dimension is not available to the callee in case of pass by value

Comment: True, but he does seem to have accounted for that with the global `n`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to read values into scores1/2 and teams1/2 before you print them or do calculations.  You could read from std::cin as in:

```
std::cout << "Enter " << n << " scores then press enter: ";
int num_scores_read;
for (num_scores_read = 0; std::cin >> scores1[num_scores_read]; ++num_scores_read)
    ;
if (!std::cin || num_scores_read < n)
{
    std::cerr << "error reading score number " << num_scores_read << '\n';
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

(similar for scores2 etc.)

OR, you could read them from a file (similar to above, but use

```
#include <fstream>
std::ifstream file(filename);
...as above but use "file" in place of "std::cin"...
```

OR, just hard code some sample values in your program to get you started:

```
int scores1[n] = { 1, 3, 5, 1, 3, 5, 4, 5, 3 };
```